# How to pass global variables to an included file in a function

Tags: php

```
function test_something() {
    global $test;
    echo '<div>';
    include("random_file.php");
    echo '</div>
}
```

random_file uses $test, but even when I define $test as global I get the undefined variable $test error when I run test_something

My actual example has about 20 variables in the file I am including and the file is 500 lines long.

Comment: you have to call the function in your random_file.php insted including file in the function

Comment: @ilya do you mean I have to put global $test inside random_file.php? random_file.php has no functions in it. It's mostly just echoing out html

Comment: is `$test` set at all ? (also I hope thats a c&p error, but the snippet lacks a single-quote and semi-colon)

Comment: I have got it working. If I *also* put $test as global inside random_file.php, it works. So at the top of random_file.php I write global $test - it works!

Comment: Where is the [testcase](http://sscce.org) with which you've been debugging this problem so far today?

Comment: Don't find any issue with the function `$test` should work on the included file `random_file.php` also. One thing i see is missing single quote and semi quote after last echo (assume that its just a typo while posting the question)

Comment: @Hardworker: It should work anyway so you did something else wrong

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think it's because my actual code is more convoluted than the simple example I posted to illustrate my point. random_file itself includes multiple files and $test is originally defined several included files up above test_something. Perhaps that is why. Regardless, it's now working when I define $test as global inside random_file :)

Comment: @Hardworker: Right, so the problem you've experienced is in code that you did not post here. That is why we require you to construct a _testcase_, **ensure that it reproduces your problem** and post that. You should already have done that as part of your own debugging. Time to delete this question as it does not have a problem in it.

Answer (score 1):

you should be fine accessing it via `global $test;` or `$GLOBALS['test']` inside `random_file.php` - there is no parametrisation of includes to my knowledge

EDIT: you should even be able to use `$test` as-is in your include since its already locally bound and includes inherit the scope

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to pass the variable to any included file , when you declare a variable in the main file , then you include others files ... you can use it wherever you want :
include a file means copy past the code in the main file.

Comment: No, it's a bit more complex than that. For example, you can `return` values from inside an `include`d file, and all functions and classes defined in the included file have the global scope.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is to define $test a global within the included file as well.

Then the undefined error goes away and $test can be used.

Comment: -1: No, this is not necessary. I tested it to check. You did something else wrong.

Comment: Well adding/removing global $test from random_file makes it work/breaks it for my code.

Comment: Then your code is not what you showed us or, possibly, you're using a particularly odd version of PHP (you neglected to state which one).